# Kafka reading old and new value from topic

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, apache-kafka

We have one producer-consumer environment, we are using Spring Boot for our project.
Kafka configuration was done by using class

```
@Configuration
@EnableKafka
public class DefaultKafkaConsumerConfig {

    @Value("${spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers}")
    private String bootstrapServers;

    @Value("${spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers-group}")
    private String bootstrapServersGroup;


    @Bean
    public ConsumerFactory<String,String> consumerDefaultFactory(){
        Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapServers);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, IntegerDeserializer.class);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
     
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, bootstrapServersGroup);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "latest");
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG, true);
     
        return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(props);
    }

    @Bean
    public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> kafkaListenerDefaultContainerFactory() {
        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
        factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerDefaultFactory());
        return factory;
    }


}
```

**SCENARIO** : We are writing some values on Kafka topics. Consider we have some topic where we are putting live data. Which have status like "live:0" for completed event and "live:1" for live event. Now when event going to be live it will get update and write on topic, and depending on this topic we are processing event.

**ISSUE** :  When event get live I read data from topic with "live:1" and processed. But when event got updated and new data updated in topic.
Here now when new data updated on topic I am able to read those data. But with new data on topic, I am receiving old data too. Because I am getting both old and new data same time my event got affected. Some time it goes live some time in completed.

Anyone give any suggestions here on this?
Why I am getting committed data and newly updated data?
Any thing I am missing here in configuration?

Comment: Can you also share the Consumer code?

Comment: I have added code here, please check.

Comment: Day before it was started working fine, only I changed group. But again it start behaving as earlier.

Answer (score 1):

you may want to check the couple of things:
-1. number of partitions
2. number of consumer

does it also means that you are re-writing the consume message to topic again, with new status?

Comment: Yes. We are writing it on same topic again and again.

Comment: This the partitions

Topic:calendar-liupre-si        PartitionCount:1        ReplicationFactor:1     Configs:
        Topic: calendar-liupre-si       Partition: 0    Leader: 0       Replicas: 0     Isr: 0

Comment: Also I tried this bin/kafka-consumer-groups.sh --zookeeper localhost:2181 --describe --group myTopicName .. it gives No topic available for consumer group provided

Comment: if possible can you share consumer code?  compare the time between auto commit and consumer polling frequency

Answer (score 0):

```
try {
  ListenableFuture<SendResult<String, String>> futureResult = this.kafkaTemplate.send(topicName, message);
  futureResult.addCallback(new ListenableFutureCallback<SendResult<String, String>>() {

    @Override
    public void onSuccess(SendResult<String, String> result) {
        log.info("Message successfully sent to topic {} with offset {} ", result.getRecordMetadata().topic(), result.getRecordMetadata().offset());
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Throwable ex) {
        FAILMESSAGELOGGER.info("{},{}", topicName, message);
        log.info("Unable to send Message to topic {} due to ", topicName, ex);
    }
      
  });
} catch (Exception e) {
  log.error("Outer Exception occured while sending message  {} to topic {}", new Object[] { message, topicName, e });
  FAILMESSAGELOGGER.info("{},{}", topicName, message);
}
```

This what we have.